# JavaScript how to split conjoining string on UpperCase and LowerCase Characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I split this string, that has LowerCase and UpperCase characters conjoined.

this is my string:

```
string = "Absolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - Cheese"
```

This is what tried, I have extracted this string from a PDF and this is information from a table:

```
let description = [];
for (let line = 0; line < lineItem_array2.length; line++) {
description += lineItem_array2[line].split(" ").slice(4, -5).join(" "); }
```

and this what I would like as the result:

```
result = "Absolute Organic Diced Tomatoes", "Cobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever Butter", "Cobs Natural Popcorn - Cheese"
```

Comment: Best solution is fix it at the source where they get joined. Beyond that, what have you tried?

Comment: This is what tried, I have extracted this string from a PDF and this is information from a table. 
let description = [];
for (let line = 0; line < lineItem_array2.length; line++) {
    description += lineItem_array2[line].split(" ").slice(4, -5).join(" ");
}

Comment: The plot thickens. Is that what is producing this string? If so need to expand on details more in the question itself. If it's not what produces the string...what is `lineItem_array2`?

Comment: What's correct? [Edit] the question with all the particulars and data sample. What you originally asked is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function for this situation this function can satisfy your need. just give your string as your input

i included another string to show  how it work

a regulear expression is used to find index and substring method is used to split the string and rest of the string is used to itrate again hope this may help someone

```js
function format(str){
    let index = 0;
    let i =0;
    let result = [];
    while(index != -1){
        index = str.search(/[a-z][A-Z][a-z]/);
        const splited = index !== -1 ? str.substring(0, index+1) : str;
        result.push(splited)
        str = str.substring(index+1, str.length);
    }
    return result
}

string = "Absolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - Cheese"

string1 = "Absolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - CheeseAbsolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - CheeseAbsolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - Cheese"

console.log("string:", format(string))
console.log("String1: ",format(string1))
```

Answer (score 1):

it is sloppy but you will get the drift

```
var splitedBySpace = "Absolute Organic Diced TomatoesCobs Natural Popcorn - Best Ever ButterCobs Natural Popcorn - Cheese".split(" ");
    var result = "";
    splitedBySpace.forEach(function(word){
        var splitByUpperCase = word.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g);
        debugger
        if(splitByUpperCase && splitByUpperCase.length>1){
            for(var i =0 ; i<= splitByUpperCase.length-1 ;i++){
                if(i== splitByUpperCase.length-1){
                    result = result.concat(splitByUpperCase[i]+" ");
                }else{
                    result = result.concat(splitByUpperCase[i]+",");
                }
                
            }
            
        }else{
            result = result.concat(word+" ")
        }
    })
    console.log(result.split(","));
```